# Requesting extended permissions from facebook?

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, dotnetopenauth, facebook-oauth

I'm having some trouble requesting extended permissions from facebook.
I do pass scope => 'email','publish_actions' and I've also set up my app on FB to *require* those permissions.

Yet, when I sign in to my site using FB, the login dialog only says "this application requests access to your public profile and friendlist"

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the default Facebook oauth client does not pass the "scope" to facebook, thus you can not request any extended permissions.

Had to go for a custom client.

Answer (score 0):

End user will be asked after they authorized your app. So it is 2 steps authorization in your case.